# using len on file count (\n)

Tags: python

I need to write a program that count the len of the lines in file and return the number of lines >= to the len size the user asked.
The problem is that len() count (\n) and I can't assume after the last line there is (\n).
How can I tell len() to not count (\n) in the end of every line?

```
def count_long_lines(filename, size):

        f=open(filename,'r')
        count_line=0
        for line in f:
                if len(line)-1>=size:
                    count_line +=1

        print count_line
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.rstrip('\n')` to remove any newlines from the line:

```
len(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: No wonder your profile picture is a ninja - just so damn quick.

Answer (score 6):

You can use (note, the `.rstrip()` to remove trailing newlines)

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print sum(1 for line in f if len(line.rstrip('\n')) >= size)
```

Comment: Heh, I didn't even see your answer when I posted my oneliner.. will remove it from mine as not to create the impression that I nicked it from you. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wouldn't worry about it - everyone will just assume I nicked it from you or something ;)

Comment: @tvdien thanks for edit - it makes more sense like that - I admit I just typed it straight into SO without thinking about that part of it

Comment: +1, a massive improvement over the original code. You might want to explain the use of the [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) and the `while` statement, however.